# Univeral Windows Platform C++ with x64 assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, uwp

I'm looking into doing C++ and assembly language on Windows 10. I'm starting with x64 asm on the desktop, then down the track I would like to try ARM asm on Win 10 IOT Core.

The project will typically have considerable amount of C++ code, and some assembly language code, but see I will see where it goes. Why use assembly? Purely for fun. This whole project is a hobby to get back into C++ and assembly.

UWP C++ appears to be the way to go, i.e. latest Microsoft programming technology. Windows Desktop C++ (i.e. Win32 or console) is still supported, but I'd rather stick with UWP.

I've had a quick read on UWP C++, learn't the basics on XAML, and C++ is coming back to me (I hadn't touched it in years).

Using Visual Studio Professional (with masm under the hood) and x64 asm.

I have a simple Hello World application. A textbox and a button. The project includes an .asm file which contains a simple function which adds two numbers and returns the result in rax. This (asm) function is called in the button click event and outputs to the textbox text.

**MainPage.xaml.cpp**

```
 extern "C" int SomeFunction();

 void LearningUWPwithCPP::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
 {
    greetingOutput->Text = SomeFunction().ToString();
 }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="contentPanel" Margin="120,30,0,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Hello World" FontSize="36"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Click the button"/>
        <Button x:Name="inputButton" Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="greetingOutput"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**TestASM.asm**

```
    .CODE
    SomeFunction PROC
            mov     rax, 5
            add     rax, 6
            ret
    SomeFunction ENDP
            END
```

Further info...

- Project Build Dependencies has masm option checked (i.e. On).
- UWP C++ compiles to native code, so it should accept asm files
- Unfortunately information on UWP and asm seems to be non-existent (no surprise here)

The problem: I'm getting an "unresolved externals" error

Helpful tips

- Intellisense is hinting the function definition on the extern declaration for my (asm) function is not found.
- I can type any garbage in the asm file and the project will successfully compile.

With these points, it's very obvious the project isn't finding my asm file. I'm not sure how to include an asm file. And I suspect extern is a remnant of the Win32 C++ days and perhaps can't be used in UWP.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at the properties for your asm file in the solution explorer.  Specifically you are looking to see if `Excluded from Build` is set to *yes* or the `Item Type` is set to something other than *Microsoft Macro Assembler*.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That's it!!! The issue was both these properties were set to blank. Setting these appropriately (as you have advised) fixed it. Thank you so much! I had spent half a day looking and trying a bunch of stuff. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Don't you normally have to use `_SomeFunction` as the asm name for your function to link with compiler-generated code on Windows?  Or does MS's assembler do that name-mangling for you?  Or does UWP include a new ABI where C and C++ symbol names aren't prefixed with `_` at all in the object files?

Comment: UWP isn't really the "lastest Microsoft technology", it's just a crippled version of the C++ desktop. The reason to use UWP is so you can sell your application on the Windows 10 store.

Comment: @RossRidge From what I've read UWP is the latest flavor. Microsoft created Metro Apps (Win8), WinRT (Win 8.1), and UWP (Win10) in a handful of years. UWP includes the Win32 & WinRT APIs (and other APIs). Also I recently learnt the 'Universal' in UWP means the developer has access to the same API across different hardware (PC, phone, Xbox, IoT...), but the app may not necessarily run anywhere. And also subsets of the API are available depending on the hardware - more reading to do by me. Crippled version of the C++ desktop? Do you mean work-in progress ? Perhaps. Confusing? Sure the heck is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the order you do things, certain properties for asm files in the VS Solution Explorer can get set incorrectly.

Common solutions include removing/re-adding the asm file from the solution explorer, or manually setting `Excluded from Build` to *no* and `Item Type` to *Microsoft Macro Assembler* for each build configuration.

Comment: Yes, set the Project Build Dependencies (masm option) before adding .asm files to the project.